# Multivariate linear regression in pymc3

Tags: python, statistics, pymc3, mcmc, emcee

I've recently started learning `pymc3` after exclusively using `emcee` for ages and I'm running into some conceptual problems.

I'm practising with Chapter 7 of [Hogg's Fitting a model to data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4686). This involves a mcmc fit to a straight line with arbitrary 2d uncertainties. I've accomplished this quite easily in `emcee`, but `pymc` is giving me some problems.

It essentially boils down to using a multivariate gaussian likelihood.

Here is what I have so far.

```
from pymc3 import  *

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 200
true_intercept = 1
true_slope = 2

true_x = np.linspace(0, 1, size)
# y = a + b*x
true_regression_line = true_intercept + true_slope * true_x
# add noise

# here the errors are all the same but the real world they are usually not!
std_y, std_x = 0.1, 0.1 
y = true_regression_line + np.random.normal(scale=std_y, size=size)
x = true_x + np.random.normal(scale=std_x, size=size)

y_err = np.ones_like(y) * std_y
x_err = np.ones_like(x) * std_x

data = dict(x=x, y=y)

with Model() as model: # model specifications in PyMC3 are wrapped in a with-statement
    # Define priors
    intercept = Normal('Intercept', 0, sd=20)
    gradient = Normal('gradient', 0, sd=20)


    # Define likelihood
    likelihood = MvNormal('y', mu=intercept + gradient * x,
                        tau=1./(np.stack((y_err, x_err))**2.), observed=y)

    # start the mcmc!
    start = find_MAP() # Find starting value by optimization
    step = NUTS(scaling=start) # Instantiate MCMC sampling algorithm
    trace = sample(2000, step, start=start, progressbar=False) # draw 2000 posterior samples using NUTS sampling
```

This raises the error: `LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square`

So I'm trying  to pass `MvNormal` the measured values for x and y (`mu`s)  and their associated measurement uncertainties (`y_err` and `x_err`). But it appears that it is not liking the 2d `tau` argument.

Any ideas? This must be possible

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do linear regression including the measurement error of ```x``` and ```y``` in the model?

Comment: Yes: 2d uncertainties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try by adapting the following model. Is a "regular" linear regression. But `x` and `y` have been replaced by Gaussian distributions. Here I am assuming not only the measured values of the input and output variables but also a reliable estimation of the their error (for example as provided by a measurement device). If you do not trust those error values you may instead try to estimate them from the data.

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    intercept = pm.Normal('intercept', 0, sd=20)
    gradient = pm.Normal('gradient', 0, sd=20)
    epsilon = pm.HalfCauchy('epsilon', 5)
    obs_x = pm.Normal('obs_x', mu=x, sd=x_err, shape=len(x))
    obs_y = pm.Normal('obs_y', mu=y, sd=y_err, shape=len(y))

    likelihood = pm.Normal('y', mu=intercept + gradient * obs_x,
                    sd=epsilon, observed=obs_y)

    trace = pm.sample(2000)
```

If you are estimating the error from the data it could be reasonable to assume they could be correlated and hence, instead of using two separate Gaussian you can use a Multivariate Gaussian. In such a case you will end up with a model like the following:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
cov = df_data.cov()

with pm.Model() as model:
    intercept = pm.Normal('intercept', 0, sd=20)
    gradient = pm.Normal('gradient', 0, sd=20)
    epsilon = pm.HalfCauchy('epsilon', 5)

    obs_xy = pm.MvNormal('obs_xy', mu=df_data, tau=pm.matrix_inverse(cov), shape=df_data.shape)

    yl = pm.Normal('yl', mu=intercept + gradient * obs_xy[:,0],
                    sd=epsilon, observed=obs_xy[:,1])

mu, sds, elbo = pm.variational.advi(n=20000)
step =  pm.NUTS(scaling=model.dict_to_array(sds), is_cov=True)
trace = pm.sample(1000, step=step, start=mu)
```

Notice that in the previous model the covariance matrix was computed from the data. If you are going to do that then I think is better to go with the first model, but if instead you are going to estimate the covariance matrix then the second model could be a sensible approach.

For the second model I use ADVI to initialize it. ADVI can be a good way to initialize models, often it works much better than find_MAP().

You may also want to check this [repository](https://github.com/davidwhogg/DataAnalysisRecipes) by David Hogg. And the book [Statistical Rethinking](http://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/) where McElreath discuss the problem of doing linear regression including the errors in the input and output variables.

Comment: That looks promising. But what is epsilon doing there?

Comment: If you were measuring adult male heights you will have a Gaussian like distribution for your sample with ```sd=epsilon``` simply because persons have different heights. Besides that you will have an error associated to measuring each individual. That is why even when we include the measurement error we still have that ```y ~ N(Beta X, sd=epsilon)```. I guess this example can be "transfered" to your problem, but I may be wrong, so feel free to make all necessary changes to the model.

Comment: So epsilon is the intrinsic scatter of the distribution, treated separately from the measurement errors?

Comment: This is all fine but what I really want is to reconstruct the likelihood [here](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?p(x_i,y_i|S_i,x,y)&space;=&space;\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{\det&space;S}}&space;\exp\{-\frac{1}{2}[Z_i&space;-&space;Z]^TS_i^{-1}[Z_i&space;-&space;Z]\}), there is no mention of epsilon, only the correlation matrix from measurement errors.

Comment: Also, your model is taking a reeeeally long time to run.

Comment: Run pretty fast on my computer, are you using ```trace = pm.sample(2000)``` or are you passing ```start``` from ```pm.find_MAP()```?

Comment: I've tried both, both run very slowly. For comparison I tested my initial 1d uncertainty model and it completes in 0.7 as opposed to what looks like an hour with 2d uncertainties.

Comment: Takes ~2 min on my computer including the uncertainties and less than 5 seconds for the regular model. From your example is not clear to me why you would like to compute a multivariate normal instead of the model I posted. But let me check in detail the link you posted and I will come back ASAP (probably tomorrow).

Comment: This is great! But if I have measurement uncertainties already on each data point, how do I work that in? That's what I'm tried to incorporate! Thanks

Comment: In that case use the first model, by writing: 

```obs_x = pm.Normal('obs_x', mu=x, sd=x_err, shape=len(x))```

you are saying that each point is modeled as a Gaussian centered at ```x``` with an uncertainty given by ```x_err```. Where ```x_err``` is a vector of uncertainties so each data point have a (potentially) different uncertainty. The same goes for ```y```.