# PYMC3: observables preprocessing random variable

Tags: pymc3

In PYMC3 the expectation is that observables are unprocessed (they are just observables!). However, I'd like to feed into a distribution data that has been preprocessed with some parameter that I'd like to be a random variable. I'm not sure PYMC3 is designed to handle this case.

Otherwise I might have to create a custom distribution where I can have the preprocessing parameter as a RV as part of the computation graph for the distribution. I'd rather not do this.

How can I have PYMC3 handle such a case (w/o writing a custom distribution)?

At the moment my code directly maps to the following diagram. It errors out when I begin to sample. It also also errors on sampling w/o even having the multinomial in the picture. But is what I'm doing correct conceptually?

[image: diagram]

Comment: In PyMC3 observables can be distributions. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677240/multivariate-linear-regression-in-pymc3) answer. Is that what do you have in mind?

Comment: Yes i've noticed that. The question still remains: The distribution is a function of a random variable. Is that variable part of the graph for the distribution that is being input into for inference purposes?

Comment: oh do you mean distribution object or distribution? I said that I noticed that b/c for example I can input into the Bernoulli distribution either a binary sequence or an estimate for p.

Comment: Is not clear for me what do you want. Maybe something like ```obs_x = pm.Normal('obs_x', mu=x, sd=x_err, shape=len(x))```, where ```x_err``` is a random variable and ```x``` is data.  Could you please post a minimal example of want you want?

Comment: i just updated my question with a diagram of what i'm trying to do to make things more concrete. i haven't posted code yet as i just want to make sure i have the concept correct first.

Comment: is there a theano shared variable issue in there somewhere??

Comment: Sorry I did not have too much time to check this, any update?

Comment: not really but i posted code to https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1436 . thanks.