# Get fitted coefficient of linear regression equation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with predicted and observed data.
The equation that predicts the data is given by: y = AfT [image: \sqrt{gh}]

With Af = constant (now at 1.35), T = wave period, g = gravitation 9.81, h = wave height.

Id like to use linear regression to find the best fitted coefficient (Af in the equation),
so that the predicted value is closer to the observed data.

I now have Af = 1.35 (from suggestion in the literature) results in r^2 = 0.5676
Ideally, I`d use python to find the best fitted coefficient for my data.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X = np.array([11.52, 11.559, 12.31, 16.46, 11.84, 7.38, 9.99, 16.72, 11.617, 11.77, 6.48, 9.035, 12.87, 11.18, 6.75])
y = np.array([25.51658407, 24.61306145, 19.4007494, 24.85111923, 25.99397106, 14.30284824, 17.69451713, 27.37460301, 22.23326366, 18.44905152, 10.28001306, 10.68681843, 28.85399089, 14.02840557, 18.41941787]).reshape((-1, 1))

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X, y)

print(clf.coef_, clf.intercept_)
```

X = observed/measured values in the field,
y = the predicted values of X using the equation

I have difficulties incorporating the actual equation and finding the best fit for Af.

Comment: Don't you want to use LinearRegression in that case? Also, from the formula it seems there is no intercept, so LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(X, y) is along the lines of what you want

Comment: what is `y= Axb sqrt(gh)` , what should that mean??? Linear equations are normally y= a*x + b, I dont understand it.

Comment: So the X-values represent measured/observed data in the field, which can be predicted using the equation y. I want to use linear regression between these 2 variables to hopefully improve the value for A, which is a constant in the equation. The constant is now 1.35 but maybe reducing/increasing it, will lead to a better fit of the linear regression and hence, increasing the  r^2 value.

Comment: Hi @SiegmundNuyts could you add in your post an explanation of all the terms in your equation?

Comment: @SiegmundNuyts from your model you can now estimate `A` by taking the log in both sides and hence rendering the equation linear: `log(y) = log(Af) + sqrt(gh)log(T)`. In this parametrisation `Af=np.exp(clf.intercept_)`. However this is a physical model and the results would probably be meaningless without an error estimate on `T` that is subsequently incorporated into the fit

Comment: @balleveryday thanks for your help. Would it be possible to expand your suggestion in the code? I`m struggling to incorporate your suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you provided but taking the log you can get fit to an ordinary least squares model from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import pandas as pd
import theano.tensor as tt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

X = np.log(np.array([11.52, 11.559, 12.31, 16.46, 11.84, 7.38, 9.99, 16.72, 11.617,
                     11.77, 6.48, 9.035, 12.87, 11.18, 6.75]))
y = np.log(np.array([25.51658407, 24.61306145, 19.4007494, 24.85111923, 
                     25.99397106, 14.30284824, 17.69451713, 27.37460301, 
                     22.23326366, 18.44905152, 10.28001306, 10.68681843, 
                     28.85399089, 14.02840557, 18.41941787]))

reg = LinearRegression().fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1))
print('Af estimate: ', np.exp(reg.intercept_))
```

This gives the following estimate of `Af`

```
Af estimate:  [2.4844087]
```

Since you don't seem to be interested in predicting new data using a model but you want the best estimate of the linear model parameters you could use [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html):

```
results = smf.ols('y ~ X + 1', data=pd.DataFrame({'y':y,'X':X})).fit()
print('Statsmodels Af estimate: ', np.exp(results.params['X']))
```

which gives 2.366 quite close to the previous value. `r^2` is similar to the one you quote.

Lastly my suggestion would be to use [pymc3](https://docs.pymc.io) and get a full bayesian fit that would allow you to naturally estimate the uncertainty of the quantity you want to measure. There is undoubtedly a bit a learning curve to pymc3 but it is great package for probabilistic programming. It allows to estimate the full posterior of your parameter space which is what most people are interested when fitting a model. An implementation for your problem could be the following:

```
with pm.Model() as model: 
    # Prior
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=1.35, sd=5) # centered around the literature value
    beta = pm.HalfNormal('beta', sd=10) # only positive values as it goes into the sqrt. Also is height always positive here?
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sd=1) 
    beta2 = pm.Deterministic('beta2', tt.sqrt(beta*9.81)) # g is very well known
    alpha_f = pm.Deterministic('alpha_f', tt.exp(alpha)) # estimate directly the output value we want

    # Likelihood
    likelihood = pm.Normal('y', mu=alpha + beta2 * X,sigma=sigma,observed=y)

    # Samplingtemp
    trace = pm.sample(init='adapt_diag')

print(pm.summary(trace))
```

This gives the following output:

```
          mean     sd  hpd_3%  hpd_97%  ...  ess_sd  ess_bulk  ess_tail  r_hat
alpha    0.781  0.544  -0.232    1.864  ...   309.0     440.0     406.0   1.01
beta     0.091  0.044   0.013    0.167  ...   517.0     438.0     359.0   1.01
sigma    0.259  0.056   0.172    0.368  ...   530.0     479.0     147.0   1.00
beta2    0.917  0.229   0.439    1.316  ...   434.0     438.0     359.0   1.01
alpha_f  2.535  1.552   0.465    5.224  ...   317.0     440.0     406.0   1.01
```

and you can see that there is a lot of uncertainty in `Af`.

However it is important to consider the data that goes in too and not overinterpret the results. At the moment you don't provide any uncertainty in either `y` or `X` or the covariance matrix. It is however very unlikely that you know these quantities perfectly so the rational thing to do is including these uncertainties in your modelling. pymc3 allow for this to be implemented naturally. My implementation above includes an estimate of uncertainty from the data but you may well have your own uncertainty from the measurement device. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677240/multivariate-linear-regression-in-pymc3) and this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4686).